# Select specific row in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I´m starting to develop in C# and SQL Server, I don´t know how to extract information from one excel specific colum.

I have this code working, but what i need it´s to compare a textbox with a specific column and get the data:

Example

```
Select * 
From T_Empleado 
Where "Specific column" = "textbox".

public void mostrarExcel()
{
    String name = "Sheet1";
    String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + "C:\\Users\\alegriad\\Desktop\\sample\\Book2.xlsx" + "; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "$]'", con);
    con.Open();

    OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(data);
    dgv_Reporte.DataSource = data;
}//mostrarExcel
```

Thank you.

Comment: How does this related to SQL Server? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/

Comment: Because you have to make a select the information inside of the excel file and then look where´s equal to a specific field in a data base in SQL Server

Comment: Do you want to read column value in each row?

Comment: Yes, that´s the point

Comment: I have to compare each row with a textbor

Comment: I think something like this, but i´m not sure how to declare the specific colum in the sentence

Comment: ("Select * From [" + name + "$] WHERE "[""specific_colum""] = " " + txtb_noEmpleado.Text + "'", con);

Comment: specific column changing or its one column always

Comment: It´s the same colum always :D

Comment: Then replace that column name with specific_column in above sample

Comment: That´s the problem, I don´t know how to declare the name of the colum, i put the name, but i couldn´t make it work :D

Comment: I think you put some extra quotes. that is why its not working check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can write your query like this

```
 OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "$] where columnName = '"+ YourTextboxValue+ "'" , con);
```

I try with sample excel like below

[image]

And my query like this

```
 OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "$] WHERE Name = 'T1'", con);
```

This works for me.

Comment: columName it´s the header of the column in the excel file, already try that way but didin´t work either :D

Comment: I try it again, and that work, THANK YOU SO MUCH :DD